# How to switch java language on a Mac?

Tags: java, macos

My system language is Chinese but I prefer using English while coding. However, my java is set to Chinese by default (e.g. compile error is in Chinese) and it looks like I can't change it to English without changing my system's language.

Comment: Set the system language back to English and reinstall JDK?

Comment: Never mind, it probably decides what language to use by looking at the current system language.

Comment: What about using JVM arg on run java e.g. `java -Duser.country=US -Duser.language=en`?

Comment: Thanks @StanislavL, I was having an issue with SBT for encoding of Javadoc and your suggestion was the only one that resolves my problem